# How to add extra text before category link on single product page in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to add "Category: " text before category link (in the same line) on Woocommerce single product page. Currently user (specially older users I am aiming my page to) may be confused what the link is. Example below (marked in yellow):

[image]

Currently code looks like this, inside "summary entry-summary" div:

```
<span class="single-product-category">
    <a href="https://www.store.domain/category-name/" rel="tag">bielizna ochronna</a>
</span>
```

**Is it doable without editing template?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I thought I will maybe share my "workaround" (as I don't like adding content to page via CSS); however still counting on some bright idea how to do it differently ;-)

```
.single-product-category:before {
  content: "Kategoria: ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

functions.php add the bottom code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_category_title', 'add_text_before_category_link', 10, 2 );

function add_text_before_category_link( $category_title, $category ) {
    // Replace "Extra Text" with the text you want to add before the category link
    return 'Extra Text '. $category_title;
}
```

Save the changes in the functions.php file.
Refresh single product page to see the updated category link.

Comment: not working, no changes

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_category_text', 1 );
function add_category_text() {
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    $term = array_pop( $terms );
    echo '<p>' . __('Category: ', 'woocommerce') . '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></p>';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it has some problems: 1. it displays only 1 category if product is placed in few, 2. it is displayed above the breadcrumbs, but should be below